# Confusion regarding the working of flowlayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, graphics2d

I have developed a small swing application in which there is a square rotating in the upper half and there is a button in the lower half which can stop/run the square to rotate.
I have used the `GridLayout` to place the rotating square and the button.
(Another alternative is to use 2 `JPanel`s ,one is with rotating square and second contains the button.Using this button appears of proper size.)

Here is the code :-

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class Rotation {
JButton jbtn=new JButton("Stop");
component jpn2=new component();    //created a JPanel named jpn2 and got a reference to its timer object.
Timer timer=jpn2.timer;
Rotation()
{


    JFrame jfrm=new JFrame("Rotating a square about a center");
    jfrm.setSize(400,400);
    jfrm.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //JPanel jpnl=new JPanel();

    //jpnl.add(jbtn);

    jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop"))
        {
            timer.stop();
            jbtn.setText("Spin");
        }
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Spin"))
        {
            timer.start();
            jbtn.setText("Stop");
        }

    }});

    jfrm.add(jpn2);
    jfrm.add(jbtn);

    //jfrm.add(new JButton("Click"));
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
    //jfrm.setOpacity(0.8f);
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException
{
    //JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new Rotation();}});
}

}

class component extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
Timer timer;
int theta=0;
component()
{
    timer=new Timer(10,this);
    timer.start();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
    g2.rotate(theta,100,100);
    g2.fillRect(50, 50, 100,100);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //Changing a global variable and then drawing the rectangle again and hence indirectly the square rotates.
    theta=theta+10;
    if(theta==360)
        theta=0;
    repaint();
}
}
```

Here is the output:-

[image: output]

But my confusion is when i decided to use `FlowLayout` instead of `GridLayout` i'm getting only the button and no rotating square.
By,as far as i have read,`FlowLayout` places components in a row and if space is less than it uses multiple rows.
Can anyone resolve this small stupid problem of mine which currently i am not able to resolve.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said (+1 to mKorbel and HFOE)

- The problem is you use `setSize(..)` rather call `pack()` before setting `JFrame` to visible.
- You will also have to override `getPrefferedSize(..)` in `JPanel` class which will return the size of your square multiplied by 2 (or else when it rotates it wont fit).
- On a side note dont throw any excpetion in `main(..)` never a good thing.

see below for the code (uses `FlowLayout` but also works with `GridLayout`):

Using `new FlowLayout()`:

[image]

Using `new GridLayout(2,1)`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Rotation {

    JButton jbtn = new JButton("Stop");
    component jpn2 = new component();    //created a JPanel named jpn2 and got a reference to its timer object.
    Timer timer = jpn2.timer;

    Rotation() {


        JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Rotating a square about a center");

        // jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Stop")) {
                    timer.stop();
                    jbtn.setText("Spin");
                }
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Spin")) {
                    timer.start();
                    jbtn.setText("Stop");
                }

            }
        });

        jfrm.add(jpn2);
        jfrm.add(jbtn);

        jfrm.pack();
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Rotation();
            }
        });
    }
}

class component extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Timer timer;
    int theta = 0;
    int width = 100, height = 100;

    component() {
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.rotate(theta, 100, 100);
        g2.fillRect(50, 50, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width * 2, height * 2);//multiply by 2 to fit while rotating
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Changing a global variable and then drawing the rectangle again and hence indirectly the square rotates.
        theta = theta + 10;
        if (theta == 360) {
            theta = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: :Thanx sir for your valuable answer.
I haven't used getPreferredSize() before.So what i understood is that the rotating square now returns its own size using getPreferredSize().
Can i also acheive the same thing with setPreferredSize,something like
    'public void setPreferredSize()
 {
  new Dimension(width*2,height*2);
 }'

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your using `setSize(...)` with these layouts which will do exactly as you request -- set the size of the GUI to that size regardless if everything doesn't show. In general  you want to avoid calling `setSize(...)`, and instead have components override `getPreferredSize()` if necessary and pack your GUI before showing it letting the components size themselves. Note that FlowLayout has its uses, but when compared to other layouts, its not the "smartest" layout in the bunch (in my opinion).

Comment: :Sir ,my question is if i can add 2 buttons to the JFrame using FlowLayout (even using setSize),then why can't i add JPanel and a button to the JFrame .Doing so only adds button and JPanel is not added or displayed.Why?

Comment: @Naveen: where in the code you've posted above do you use FlowLayout? It's always best to post the offending code.

Comment: :Sir,in the above code i just want to replace 'GridLayout(2,1)' with 'FlowLayout()'.And i'm getting only button ,but no JPanel containing my rotating square.
Now ,what i want is to get them both using FlowLayout.If not possible,Then why?

Comment: @Naveen: then  you haven't done what I've recommended -- override your drawing panel's getPreferredSize method, use pack(), and not use setSize. Why are you asking for further advice when you haven't tried the advice given?

Answer (score 3):

`FlowLayout` accepting only `PreferredSize` came from it childs, `JComponents` aren't resizable continuously with it parent

`GridLayout` (your issue) take `PreferredSize` from most larger and wider `JComponents` and to set the same `Dimmension` for rest of `JComponents` in  the container, `JComponents` are resizable and continuously with it parent

have to use pre_implemented `LayoutManager` for `JFrame`, use `Borderlayout`, `JComponents` are resizable and continuously with it parent (CENTER area only, rest only with one of coordinates)

remove

```
jfrm.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
```

and to change

```
jfrm.add(jpn2); 
jfrm.add(jbtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

notice for `JFrame`

```
frm.add(jpn2); equals frm.add(jpn2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: :Sir,the issue i'm having is that if i can add 2 buttons using FlowLayout, then why can't i add a JPanel and a button (Doing that only adds button,JPanel is not added or displayed).